# How to point single subdomain to same server with two IP address

Tags: dns, ip, subdomain

For example, I've a **server** hosted at my home with **2 NIC**s for redundancy obviously.

- **NIC1** has been assigned with the public IP `103.204.82.22` from **ISP1**
- **NIC2** has been assigned with the public IP `144.110.12.64` from **ISP2**

I can access the server with both IP as usual.

Now, I have a *domain* **`acme.com`**. I've created a *subdomain* **`server.acme.com`**. I want to point **`server.acme.com`** to both the IPs so that in case one ISP fails to provide connectivity my server still remains online with the other one.

I've already tried with **A** and **CNAME** records. But it isn't working. It's working with A record if I use only one IP for the subdomain.

Can anyone tell me what and how can I point both the IPs to the single subdomain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what 'isn't working' what errors you're getting, what did happen etc

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called DNS round robin, but that won't give you your expected outcome.

Anything you do with DNS if one ISP connection is down, traffic will still go there.

Comment: then what is the solution to redundancy?

Comment: You need a hardware solution, a router which supports dual ISP for example
And dynamic dns

Comment: that's a good idea. I've already tried DUAL WAN FAILOVER method. But the problem there is when one line goes down so goes down the IP

Comment: That's where dynamic DNS comes in.
You want to make sure the TTL on the DNS is short, some routers will come with dynamic DNS support built in, others you might need an app running on your server.

It sends the IP(s) currently available to the DNS server, requests can then get the most up to date information

Comment: If he can access the machine via the IP addresses, then DNS round robin would be exactly what he is looking for. DDNS is simply a way of dynamically updating DNS records.

Comment: If isp1 goes down DNS will still round robin to it.
Therefore not giving the redundancy akjon is after.

Comment: If ISP1 goes down, then the client will notice that it can't connect, and fall back to using ISP2, there would be an initial delay while the client waited for ISP1 to timeout, but once that had happened the client would mark ISP1 as failed and solely use ISP2

Answer (score 0):

You may have your terminology mixed up a little to start with.

in this case, I suspect you really mean that `server.acme.com` is a host record, rather than a subdomain. (A subdomain would mean that the server address would be at `servername.server.acme.com`)

If you create an A record, and put both IP addresses in, and keep the TTL (time to live) short, then when a client wants to contact your machine it will randomly pick one of the addresses. If that address is unavailable, it will move on to the next. If that address stops working, it will keep trying it for the 'TTL' time.

Presuming that the IP addresses don't change, which would be a different problem altogether, then this provide basic load balancing and failover to both connections.

Amazon provide a more advanced type of DNS, that will actively monitor your connections and only provide responses that are live. - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html

Comment: If isp1 goes down DNS will still round robin to it.
Therefore not giving the redundancy akjon is after.